# What is wrong with my upstart job file?

Tags: ubuntu, upstart

I wrote a little script for upstart and included a log function in the executable file, but there is no log output. When starting the program manually, it works fine.
Here is the `.conf` file located in `/etc/init/`:

```
description "upstart file for the program"

start on startup
stop on shutdown

respawn

exec /usr/local/bin/program
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with upstart 1.12.1.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should follow the [Ubuntu upstart howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpstartHowto)

A couple of points that may be of interest to you:

- the scripts are located in /etc/init.d
- they need a symbolic link to them in a /etc/rcN.d folder - N = runlevel

Comment: My script is actually a upstart job, which should be in `/etc/init` according to the link and the Upstart cookbook.

Comment: In that case: "start on startup" - has /usr already been mounted?  Where is the log located?